# Как сделать фон картинки QPixmap прозрачным в PyQt5 QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgraphicsview

**Имеется**: программа-игра, написанная на *PyQt5*. При нажатии на кнопку `Начать игру` появляются утки, которые создаются с помощью класса `Duck` на QGraphics-поле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема**: фон у данных картинок (уток) не прозрачный, хотя формат картинок `PNG`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать фон данных уток прозрачным.

**Код**:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QGroupBox, \
    QRadioButton, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, \
    QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPixmap, QIcon, QBrush, QPen

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_NAME = 'Истребитель уток'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Images\\main_logo.png'

MAIN_FONT = "Times"
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8

DUCKS_QTY = 8


class Duck(QGraphicsPixmapItem): # класс утки
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        duck_pixmap = QPixmap("goose.png") # загрузка картинки
        self.setPixmap(duck_pixmap)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setPos(random.choice([-110, 600]), random.choice([230, 250, 270]))

        self.duck_reverse_x = "Left"
        self.duck_reverse_y = "Up"


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    ducks = []
    duck_move_timer = QTimer()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.draw_brush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        self.draw_pen = QPen(Qt.red)

        self.duck_move_timer.setInterval(20)
        self.duck_move_timer.timeout.connect(self.timeStep)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.task_label = QLabel()

        self.control_label = QLabel()
        self.start_button = QPushButton()
        self.quit_button = QPushButton()
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.duck_move_timer.stop)
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.game_stopped)

        self.mode_label = QLabel()
        self.first_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.first_rbutton.clicked.connect(self.set_timer_interval)
        self.second_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.second_rbutton.clicked.connect(self.set_timer_interval)
        self.third_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.third_rbutton.clicked.connect(self.set_timer_interval)

        self.results_label = QLabel()
        self.play_time_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Время игры")
        self.play_attempts_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Число попыток")

        self.qgraphic_background_image = QPixmap("backimage.jpg")
        self.background_graph_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.background_graph_scene.selectionChanged.connect(
            self.handle_qgraphic_selection)
        self.graphic_view = QGraphicsView(self.background_graph_scene)
        self.graphic_view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphic_view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphic_view.setFixedSize(565, 385)
        self.background_graph_scene.addPixmap(self.qgraphic_background_image)

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.task_label.setText("Задача: убейте всех уток за меньшее число попыток.")
        self.task_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.task_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.control_label.setText("Управление")
        self.start_button.setText("Начать игру")
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.build_qgraphic_ducks)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.game_started)
        self.quit_button.setText("Закончить игру")

        self.mode_label.setText("Режим:")
        self.mode_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.first_rbutton.setText("1-я скорость")
        self.first_rbutton.setChecked(True)
        self.second_rbutton.setText("2-я скорость")
        self.third_rbutton.setText("3-я скорость")

        self.results_label.setText("Результаты:")
        self.results_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.play_time_qedit.setDisabled(True)
        self.play_attempts_qedit.setDisabled(True)

    def create_layers(self):
        outline = '''
                    QGroupBox {
                        margin-top: 2ex;
                    }
                    QGroupBox::title {
                        subcontrol-origin: margin;
                        left: 3ex;
                    }
                    '''

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        task_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        task_layout.addWidget(self.task_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(task_layout)

        self.control_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.control_label.text())
        self.control_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        control_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.control_groupbox)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.control_groupbox)

        self.mode_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.mode_label.text())
        self.mode_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        mode_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.mode_groupbox)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.first_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.second_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.third_rbutton)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.mode_groupbox)

        self.result_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.results_label.text())
        self.result_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        result_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.result_groupbox)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_time_qedit)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_attempts_qedit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.result_groupbox)

        background_image_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        background_image_layout.addWidget(self.graphic_view)
        main_layout.addLayout(background_image_layout)

    def game_started(self):
        rbuttons = [self.first_rbutton, self.second_rbutton, self.third_rbutton]
        for rbutton in rbuttons:
            rbutton.setDisabled(True)
        self.start_button.setDisabled(True)

    def game_stopped(self):
        rbuttons = [self.first_rbutton, self.second_rbutton, self.third_rbutton]
        for rbutton in rbuttons:
            rbutton.setDisabled(False)
        self.start_button.setDisabled(False)

    def build_qgraphic_ducks(self):
        print('Starting')
        self.remove_qgraphic_ducks()
        for duck_number in range(DUCKS_QTY):
            duck = Duck()
            self.ducks.append(duck)
            self.background_graph_scene.addItem(duck)
        self.duck_move_timer.start()

    def remove_qgraphic_ducks(self):
        self.ducks = []
        all_qgraphic_objects = self.background_graph_scene.items()
        for qgraphic_object in all_qgraphic_objects:
            if type(qgraphic_object) != QGraphicsPixmapItem:
                self.background_graph_scene.removeItem(qgraphic_object)

    def handle_qgraphic_selection(self):
        all_qgraphic_objects = self.background_graph_scene.selectedItems()
        if len(all_qgraphic_objects) != 0:
            for qgraphic_object in all_qgraphic_objects:
                self.background_graph_scene.removeItem(all_qgraphic_objects[0])

    def set_timer_interval(self):
        rbuttons = [self.first_rbutton, self.second_rbutton, self.third_rbutton]
        rbutton_num = 1
        for rbutton in rbuttons:
            if rbutton.isChecked() and rbutton_num == 1:
                self.duck_move_timer.setInterval(20)
                self.duck_move_timer.timeout.connect(self.timeStep)
            elif rbutton.isChecked() and rbutton_num == 2:
                self.duck_move_timer.setInterval(50)
                self.duck_move_timer.timeout.connect(self.timeStep)
            elif rbutton.isChecked() and rbutton_num == 3:
                self.duck_move_timer.setInterval(100)
                self.duck_move_timer.timeout.connect(self.timeStep)
        rbutton_num += 1

    def timeStep(self):
        for duck in range(DUCKS_QTY):
            if self.ducks[duck].pos().x() <= 35 or self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_x == "Right":
                self.ducks[duck].setPos(self.ducks[duck].pos().x() + random.randint(0, 5), self.ducks[duck].pos().y())
                if self.ducks[duck].pos().x() >= 480:
                    self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_x = "Left"
            elif self.ducks[duck].pos().x() >= 565 or self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_x == "Left":
                self.ducks[duck].setPos(self.ducks[duck].pos().x() - random.randint(0, 5), self.ducks[duck].pos().y())
                if self.ducks[duck].pos().x() <= 35:
                    self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_x = "Right"

            if self.ducks[duck].pos().y() <= 10 or self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_y == "Down":
                self.ducks[duck].setPos(self.ducks[duck].pos().x(), self.ducks[duck].pos().y() + random.randint(0, 3))
                if self.ducks[duck].pos().y() >= 300:
                    self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_y = "Up"
            elif self.ducks[duck].pos().y() >= 300 or self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_y == "Up":
                self.ducks[duck].setPos(self.ducks[duck].pos().x(), self.ducks[duck].pos().y() - random.randint(0, 3))
                if self.ducks[duck].pos().y() <= 10:
                    self.ducks[duck].duck_reverse_y = "Down"

            self.background_graph_scene.update()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Картинка утки, подпишите её как `goose.png`**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Картинка фона, подпишите её как `backimage.jpg`**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам сервис [Удаление фона на изображениях](https://www.remove.bg/ru/) пользуйтесь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оох, спасибо xD. Просто я уже пробовал удалить фон, но это почему-то не сработало)